# Checking for additional privileges with policy based authorization in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.1 with policy based authorization against Active Directory groups configured in `appsettings.json`. I have several calls to configure each policy similar to the following:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("UserGroup"), policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.RequireRole(jsonAuthSection.UserGroup);
    });
});
```

I decorate various API controllers with different policies as needed as follows:

```
[Authorize("UserGroup")]
```

However, I now have models where some properties require administrative membership to change. To facilitate this, I use nullable types and when the property is bound (implying a change / value was specified) I need to check for additional permissions:

```
AuthorizationResult isAdmin = await this.authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(this.User, "AdminGroup");

if (updateModel.Locked != null && !isAdmin.Succeeded)
{
    return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized, "some message");
}

// More checks...
```

Users are prompted for credentials instead of simply failing. What is a more appropriate strategy for accomplishing this?

Comment: Have you tried returning a 403 - Forbidden instead?

Comment: Brilliant, write that up as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be returning **403 - Forbidden**.